# Prevent logged user from editing data which does not belong to him

Tags: oauth, owin, umbraco, umbraco7

I have Members in my Umbraco 7 website. Each member can login to the front-end site and edit pages which only the member can edit. I use UmbracoIdentity for managing Members. 
I have a custom property Page (MNTP) on my Member doc Type which specify which pages a Member can edit. On user profile page I show a list with the alloed pages for edit from this custom property like this:

```
 var pages = profileModel.MemberProperties.FirstOrDefault(p => p.Alias == "pages").Value;
foreach (var item in pages.Split(','))
{
    DetailsPage obj = Umbraco.TypedContent(item) as DetailsPage;
    <a href="/edit-page?pageId=@obj.Id">@obj.H1Title</a> 
 }
```

When a member clicks on the link (domain.com/edit-page?pageId=3242) I have action method which loads data for the page:

```
@Html.Action("GetPageDetails", "Edit", new { id = pageId })
```

What I want to prevent is if a Member change pageId query string manualy and his custom property Pages does not contain this pageId to redirect him to user profile page with the list with his allowed pages. 
 I need an idea how to restrict logged in member to edit only the pages that are assigned in the property Pages. 
I have successfully added the pages IDs in Claims and I can perform the check in each method. But my methods are a lot. Is there some best practice or a solution which does not require to go over all methods.

Thanks

Comment: Could you show a bit of code? I'm interesed in how a user can edit a page in the frontend. I've added similar functionality to an application using a custom checkbox picker (nupickers) that creates a list of pages. Then added a little piece of code to the master page that enables/disables the edit functionality based on the id and the member permissions

Comment: Hi Mark, I updated my question adding more details